# Derby Database - Determine Levels in a Hierarchy to convert a DB -> DefaultMutableTreeNode Java object

Tags: java, sql, hierarchy, derby, jtree

I've got a table in Derby:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IMPORT_RULES (
   RULEID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
   PARENTID  INTEGER,
   NAME      VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (RULEID)
)
```

PARENTID is the RULEID of the parent, but the depth of the parent/child relationship is unknown.

My goal is to create a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` that represents the hierarchical data.

My thought was that the best way to do this would be to have a SQL query that returned the "levels" of every item in the database and cycle backwards from the lowest level to the highest.

My problem is that I can't seem to come up with said query for Derby.

Any ideas on how to generate this query, or otherwise achieve the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) is an acceptable alternative, it supports [*Recursive Queries*](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries). See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599682/230513) regarding custom tree models.

Comment: This is a very interesting possibility. By any chance do you know if H2 supports more than one connection to the same database when its embedded? (This is a long shot, but figured I'd ask).

Comment: [Yes](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#web_applications); also consider adding the [tag:h2] tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is going to be a single query that could achieve your goal. If there was it must be over my head. Most efficient way, in terms of performance, wouldn't it be nice to save the "depth" in a separate table. So simply putting, you save the tree node data in IMPORT_RULES table and save the depth of each node in a separate table, say IMPORT_RULE_LEVEL, which holds node id and relevant depth to global root node.

But apparently, sometime you might need to have batch updates if you insert a new node in the middle of a branch. If all your logic needs to do is just append children nodes, then a separate table would be a good option.